# Ubuntu 14.04 will not Boot with AMD RadeonHD 7990 Card

Tags: boot, grub2, ati, gpu

I have been using Ubuntu for a while but not very good in terminal commands or solving issues. I have a problem with booting up when I attach my GPU, where grub freezes to a black screen. If detach the GPU the system boots fine. By the way I have 4 Radeon HD 7990 MSI GPUs where 3 are on 16x1 raisers and 1 is on 16x16 raiser. The GPU on 16x1 seem not conflict the boot as I don't need to unplug them to have successful boot.

I have reinstalled the latest Catalyst drivers and set the grub to nomodeset ([following this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)) but it hasn't worked. I even tried a fix with boot repair and here is the url paste it gave me: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7936415/

I have a APU A10 processor with a A88X mobo so I am not sure if that conflicts...

Can someone help please, let me know if you need any other info

Cheers
Vini

Answer (score 0):

Try using "nomodeset" in the boot loader

-Hold Left Shift during power on to get into GRUB
-Press 'e' to edit the boot command line
-Locate the Linux line that has other commands like quiet and nosplash
-Add "nomodeset" (w/out quotes) to the line (I usually place it after "quiet")
-Press F10 to boot
-Once logged in, install the proprietary driver

With add-in cards the other problem I have experienced before is Linux trying to use the wrong device, I don't remember the commands to resolve that though, it involved grep'ing the PCIe bus address of the card and editing a file somewhere to point the system to it.